# I have to write two SQL statements in order to update a record, is there a better way to do it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I want to update a table:

```
$result=mysql_query("select balance from tablename where userid='$userid")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$accountbalance=$row['balance'];
if($accountbalance>$cost)
{
$result=mysql_query("update tablename set balance-'$cost' where userid='$userid")or die(mysql_error());
}
else {
...
}
```

You see, I have to write two mysql statements, is there a better way to do it?

```
mysql_query("update users set balance=balance+'$pwbalance'-'$totalprice' where memberid='$memberid' and (balance+'$pwbalance'-'$totalprice')>=0")or die(mysql_error());
$count=mysql_affected_rows();
```

Why is $count is 0 even I think it should be 1?

Comment: Do you know that `$count` is 1 in your original, two query approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET balance=balance-$cost WHERE userid=$userid AND balance > $cost
```

Comment: If you check that balance > cost I'd make damn sure that at least 1 row got updated.  "Not enough balance, 0 rows updated' :-)

Comment: so I use mysql_affected_rows to get the result?

Comment: Right - I would just like to point out that in the answer, it should probably read "$cost" instead of just "cost" (in both cases without the double quotes)

Comment: Roland, you're right, I must have misread this as for some reason I had the idea that `cost` was another column. Fixed.

Comment: mysql_query("update users set balance=balance+'$pwbalance'-'$totalprice' where memberid='$memberid' and (balance+'$pwbalance'-'$totalprice')>=0")or die(mysql_error());
$count=mysql_affected_rows();
Why is $count is 0 even I think it should be 1?